# Not able to use @angular-service-worker in my NX-workspace

Tags: angular, service-worker, ngrx, angular-service-worker, nrwl

Because I'm using `Angular CLI: 1.5.0`, I have to add all files that automatically get added when you use `ng add @angular/pwa` with `Angular CLI:^ 6.0.0`, but not seeing any service worker getting registered.

Can anybody tell me what should be the folder structure for these files (`manifest.json`, `ngsw-config.json` etc) in my NX environment?

Answer (score 0):

Keep both the files in your root folder. 
Register the service worker in your app module by importing

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {
  enabled: environment.production
})
```

then enable **`"serviceWorker": true`** in production configuration section of angular.json file